# Infinite output using fscanf

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
char Name[100];
int Class;
void Display(FILE* p) {
    while ((fscanf(p, "Name: %s, Class: %d\n", Name, &Class))!= EOF) {
        printf("Name: %s, Class: %d\n", Name, Class);
    }
    
}
void Append(FILE* p) {
   
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s", Name);
        printf("Class: ");
        scanf("%d", &Class);
        fprintf(p, "Name: %s, Class: %d\n", Name, Class);
    }
}
void Writing(FILE* p) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s", Name);
        printf("Class: ");
        scanf("%d", &Class);
        fprintf(p, "Name: %s, Class: %d\n", Name, Class);
    }
}
int main() {
    char a;
    FILE* p;
    do {
        
        int Choice;
        printf("Choose a choice\n1 for display\n2 for appending data\n3 for writing\nChoice: ");
        scanf("%d", &Choice);
        switch (Choice) {
        case 1: {
            p = fopen("NewFile.txt", "r");
            Display(p);
            fclose(p);
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            p = fopen("NewFile.txt", "a");
            Append(p);
            fclose(p);
            break; 
        }
        case 3: {
            p = fopen("NewFile.txt", "w");
            Writing(p);
            fclose(p);
            break;
        }
        }
        printf("Do you want to continue, y for yes: ");
        scanf(" %c", &a);
    } while (a == 'y');   
}
```

Tried replacing

```
while ((fscanf(p, "Name: %s, Class: %d\n", Name, &Class))!= EOF)
```

with

```
while ((fscanf(p, "%s, %d\n", Name, &Class))!= EOF)
```

which gave

```
Name: Name:, Class: 0
Name: ff,, Class: 0
Name: Class:, Class: 0
Name: 5, Class: 0
Name: Name:, Class: 0
Name: gg,, Class: 0
Name: Class:, Class: 0
Name: 8, Class: 0
```

as output..

Also tried not writing Name and Class in `fprintf` and `fscanf` functions but it still didn't work..

Comment: I'm tempted to close the question as a duplicate of [What is the effect of trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string)  In general, trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string is a bad idea; the user has to predict what the next input requires.

Comment: You also have the problem that you're checking for EOF from `scanf()`, but it will return `0` if it cannot understand the input before getting input.  You have `"%s, %d\n"` — that is guaranteed to fail because the `%s` stops scanning when the next character is white space (or EOF), and then the scanning won't get a comma (because the character in the input is white space), so the scanning stops.  Test for `if (scanf("%s, %d\n", …) == 2) { …OK… } else { …error… }`.  And use a format string like `" %99[^,], %d"` for the format string.  The `%[…]` (scan set) conversion does not skip white space.

Comment: Don't compare `scanf` and friends with `EOF` – check the number of conversions that were expected. If that is incorrect you can *then* figure out if it was EOF or stalled.

Comment: See also [A Beginner's Guide Away From `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).  The `scanf()` family of functions are tricky to use correctly.  Often, the best (or, at least, a good) technique is to read a line of data (e.g. with `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`) and then parse that with `sscanf()`.  Sometimes, more ad hoc parsing tools are appropriate.  The `scanf()` functions do not necessarily safely handle integers which are too large or too small — presenting such numbers to the functions invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: In particular it is *user input* which is tricky, becuase you need a recovery strategy. A formatted file is less so, because if it's garbage you can't process it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*Converting my comments into an answer.*</sup>

You need to read [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19499060/15168). In general, trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string is a bad idea; the user has to predict what the next input requires.  Almost all conversion specifiers skip leading white space (newlines, blanks, tabs, etc).  The three exceptions are `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n`.

However, you have other problems than just the trailing white space in the format strings.

You also have the problem that you're checking for EOF from `scanf()`, but it will return 0 if it cannot understand the input before successfully converting any input.  It returns the number of items successfully scanned.  You should therefore test that you got the expected number of inputs.  For example:

```
while ((fscanf(p, "Name: %s, Class: %d\n", Name, &Class)) == 2)
```

You might need to capture the value from `fscanf()` to distinguish between errors and EOF.  You might want to read up to the next newline if you get one or zero returned.  (See also the advice below about reading lines and then parsing them.)

You also have `"%s, %d\n"` — but that is guaranteed to fail because the `%s` stops scanning when the next character is white space (or EOF), and then the scanning won't get a comma (because the character in the input is white space), so the scanning stops.

Use a format string like this:

```
" %99[^,], %d"
```

The leading space skips white space; the `99` prevents buffer overflows.  The `[^,]` scan set looks for anything but a comma.

See also [A Beginner's Guide Away From `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

The [`scanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) family of functions are tricky to use correctly. Often, the best (or, at least, a good) technique is to read a line of data (e.g. with [`fgets()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) and then parse that with sscanf().  One major advantage of this is that you can report the whole line that triggered the error, rather than just what was left unconverted by `scanf()`.  Sometimes, more ad hoc parsing tools are appropriate.  The `scanf()` functions do not necessarily safely handle integers which are too large or too small — presenting such numbers to the functions invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: The trailing newline is bad, however `"%s, %d"` could be `"%s ,%d"` to prevent blockage. The space was in the wrong place (not needed before `%d`).

Comment: The input data would need a space before the comma for that to work, @WeatherVane.  The `%s` reads up to the blank after the comma in the input, and then looks for a comma — which it doesn't find because it has already been read.  (Using `scanf()` correctly is ***really*** hard!)

Comment: That's what you said: "if there is whitespace in the input *before the comma*, it won't get further". And if there is, the space I inserted in the `scanf` format will deal with it. `scanf` is tricky.